# Best way to store and use a large text-file in python

Tags: python, boggle

I'm creating a networked server for a boggle-clone I wrote in python, which accepts users, solves the boards, and scores the player input.  The dictionary file I'm using is 1.8MB (the ENABLE2K dictionary), and I need it to be available to several game solver classes.  Right now, I have it so that each class iterates through the file line-by-line and generates a hash table(associative array), but the more solver classes I instantiate, the more memory it takes up.

What I would like to do is import the dictionary file once and pass it to each solver instance as they need it.  But what is the best way to do this?  Should I import the dictionary in the global space, then access it in the solver class as globals()['dictionary']?  Or should I import the dictionary then pass it as an argument to the class constructor?  Is one of these better than the other?  Is there a third option?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you create a dictionary.py module, containing code which reads the file and builds a dictionary, this code will only be executed the first time it is imported. Further imports will return a reference to the existing module instance. As such, your classes can:

```
import dictionary

dictionary.words[whatever]
```

where dictionary.py has:

```
words = {}

# read file and add to 'words'
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is essentially a singleton at this point, the usual arguments against globals apply.  For a pythonic singleton-substitute, look up the "borg" object.

That's really the only difference.  Once the dictionary object is created, you are only binding new references as you pass it along unless if you explicitly perform a deep copy.  It makes sense that it is centrally constructed once and only once so long as each solver instance does not require a private copy for modification.

Answer (score 1):

Adam, remember that in Python when you say:

```
a = read_dict_from_file()
b = a
```

... you are not actually *copying* `a`, and thus using more memory, you are merely making `b` another reference to the same object.

So basically **any** of the solutions you propose will be far better in terms of memory usage.  Basically, read in the dictionary **once** and then hang on to a reference to that.  Whether you do it with a global variable, or pass it to each instance, or something else, you'll be referencing the same object and not duplicating it.

Which one is most Pythonic?  That's a whole 'nother can of worms, but here's what I would do personally:

```
def main(args):
  run_initialization_stuff()
  dictionary = read_dictionary_from_file()
  solvers = [ Solver(class=x, dictionary=dictionary) for x in len(number_of_solvers) ]
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your dict contains, you may be interested in the 'shelve' or 'anydbm' modules. They give you dict-like interfaces (just strings as keys and items for 'anydbm', and strings as keys and any python object as item for 'shelve') but the data is actually in a DBM file (gdbm, ndbm, dbhash, bsddb, depending on what's available on the platform.) You probably still want to share the actual database between classes as you are asking for, but it would avoid the parsing-the-textfile step as well as the keeping-it-all-in-memory bit.